# pip install -r requirements.txt not installing libraries in vs code virtual environement

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have created virtual environment in VS code. When i am doing the command pip install -r requirements.txt.
[image]

Still the vs code says no such module found. However, if i individually do pip install  and it works like a charm. why ?
My requirements.txt file are

```
Flask==1.1.2
joblib==1.0.1
keras==2.6.0
matplotlib==3.3.4
numpy==1.21.2
pandas==1.3.3
requests==2.25.1
scikit_learn==1.0.2
seaborn==0.11.1
xgboost==1.5.1
utils==1.0.1
jellyfish==0.8.9
langdetect==1.0.9
nltk==3.6.1
spacy==3.2.0
textblob==0.17.1
vaderSentiment==3.3.2
ipython==7.30.1
gapminder==0.1
mlxtend==0.19.0
networkx==2.5
squarify==0.4.3
pandas-profiling==3.1.0
plotly==5.3.1
scikit_image==0.18.1
scipy==1.7.1
nbformat
squarify==0.4.3
gapminder==0.1
tensorflow==2.7
ipywidgets
```

Comment: Can you add the error message itself?

Comment: It says Module not Found error but if i individually do pip install for the module it works totally fine.

Comment: Does it say that for the requirments.txt or a specific package?

Comment: Are you doing a `Restart Runtime` after installing libraries? Some of the libraries require `Restart Runtime` after installation. It will  be on top of your menu bar.

Comment: I tried but it says the same thing again and again. Seems like the libraries aren't getting installed but installing individually is working.

Comment: How are you creating and activating/accessing the virtual environment? Are you running `pip install -r requirements.txt` and `pip install` (for each library) from the same place?

Comment: @KumarHemjeet Are you sure that you use the right pip? I once added `pip` as alias directly in my `.zshrc` file. I then noticed that this overruled the pip in my venv. removing the alias worked for me.

Comment: Whats the error exactly?

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xyz'` 
or
`ERROR: No matching distribution found for xyz`

These are 2 different errors coming at different times and different use-cases.

Answer (score 2):

I think this might happen, because you install it to python global env. Try to add the name of your venv when calling `pip install` like so:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt -e <your current environment>
```

For more details, refer to the [official docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a dependency conflict: `tensorflow 2.7.0` depends on `keras<2.8` and `>=2.7.0rc0`?

When the dependencies are installed with `pip install -r requirements.txt` the installation of `tensorflow` is aborted, because of the conflict.

When the dependencies are installed one by one `keras 2.6.0` is installed first, then `tensorflow 2.7.0`. During the installation of `tensorflow 2.7.0` `keras 2.6.0` is removed and replaced with `keras-2.7.0`.

```
Installing collected packages: keras
  Attempting uninstall: keras
    Found existing installation: keras 2.6.0
    Uninstalling keras-2.6.0:
      Successfully uninstalled keras-2.6.0
Successfully installed keras-2.7.0
```

Comment: This wasn't the fully correct answer, but it got me thinking; the main thing is if your packages are not using current or up-to-date libraries ie. 1.21.0 instead of 1.22.0 and one dependency fails the entire install fails. Update all failing packages then everything should install and be able to be picked up.

Answer (score 1):

With Python 3.10 I got this error when using your `requirements.txt`:

```py
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement scipy==1.7.1 
(from versions: 0.8.0, 0.9.0, 0.10.0, 0.10.1, 0.11.0, 0.12.0, 0.12.1, 0.13.0, 0.13.1,
0.13.2, 0.13.3, 0.14.0, 0.14.1, 0.15.0, 0.15.1, 0.16.0, 0.16.1, 0.17.0, 0.17.1, 0.18.0,
0.18.1, 0.19.0, 0.19.1, 1.0.0b1, 1.0.0rc1, 1.0.0rc2, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0rc1, 1.1.0,
1.2.0rc1, 1.2.0rc2, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.3.0rc1, 1.3.0rc2, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2,
1.3.3, 1.4.0rc1, 1.4.0rc2, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0rc1, 1.5.0rc2, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3,
1.5.4, 1.6.0rc1, 1.6.0rc2, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.8.0rc1, 1.8.0rc2, 1.8.0rc3,
1.8.0rc4, 1.8.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for scipy==1.7.1
```

I suggest utilizing [pip-compile](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools) to come up with a compatible list of modules. You'll pin your wanted modules and desired version in `requirements.in`, then run `pip-compile` to generate your `requirements.txt`.  From here, install from your `requirements.txt` like normal.